# Query returning wrong result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    A.id AS id, 
    Group_Concat(B.value) AS values, 
    Group_Concat(C.ac_id) AS ac_id, 
    Concat(D.first_name,' ',D.last_name) AS updatedBy
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
    ON A.id = B.id 
LEFT JOIN C 
    ON A.id = C.id 
LEFT JOIN D 
    ON A.modified_by = D.user_id 
WHERE 
    A.status!='deleted' 
    AND A.created_by = '18'  
GROUP BY A.id;
```

Table B & C has multiple rows corressponding to A.id thats why i am using group_concat on those fields but i am getting wrong result for those grouped columns.query return result like

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| id      | values                  | ac_id                   | updatedBy   |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|       8 | A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D | 1,5,6,1,5,6,1,5,6,1,5,6 | Abdul       |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

but i need output like this

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| id      | values                  | ac_id                   | updatedBy   |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|       8 | A,B,C,D                 | 1,5,6                   | Abdul       |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in your `GROUP_CONCAT()`. This way duplicates don't get displayed.

```
SELECT 
A.id AS id, 
Group_Concat(DISTINCT B.value) AS values, 
Group_Concat(DISTINCT  C.ac_id) AS ac_id, 
Concat(D.first_name,' ',D.last_name) AS updatedBy
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.id = C.id 
LEFT JOIN D ON A.modified_by = D.user_id 
WHERE A.status!='deleted' AND A.created_by = '18'  GROUP BY A.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved already!

Straight out of [the documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> To eliminate duplicate values, use the `DISTINCT` clause.

There's even a handy example of its use.

**Please use the documentation.**